# SCRIPT 600: Invalid target element for this operation. (IE Only)

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a ajax calendar I am working on, it is working fine in Chrome, Safari & Firefox as usual. However It is not working in IE9 or below.

I am getting the following error **SCRIPT 600: Invalid target element for this operation.**

It is a WP plugin, but this is the code

```
function show_micro_ajax(response) {
    document.getElementById('wp-calendar').innerHTML = response;
}

function microAjax(url, cF) {
    this.bF = function(caller, object) {
        return function() {
            return caller.apply(object, new Array(object));
        }
    };
    this.sC = function(object) {
        if (this.r.readyState == 4) {
            this.cF(this.r.responseText);
        }
    };
    this.gR = function() {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else return false;
    };
    if (arguments[2]) this.pb = arguments[2];
    else this.pb = "";
    this.cF = cF;
    this.url = url;
    this.r = this.gR();
    if (this.r) {
        this.r.onreadystatechange = this.bF(this.sC, this);
        if (this.pb != "") {
            this.r.open("POST", url, true);
            this.r.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            this.r.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
        } else {
            this.r.open("GET", url, true);
        }
        this.r.send(this.pb);
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to support IE6, remove the ActiveX line,
otherwise, reverse your test:

```
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   else return false;
```

I'm not sure how the instance becomes an array here,
and possibly IE doesn't either, especially if one of the members in sn ActiveX object.

```
return caller.apply(object, new Array(object))
```